# Is it possible to write a Firestore rule that only allow an operation if it's a part of certain transactions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, transactions, firebase-security

I have a document called `accountA`. It has a `balance` field. Now `accountA` has a sub-collection called `transactions`. Each document in `transactions` has `amount` field. I already wrote a transaction using Firestore SDK to  add/remove a `transaction` doc and then update its corresponding account.

Is there a rule I can write so that a `transaction` doc can be written only if there's a matching update to the `balance` of the corresponding account in the same transaction? Or am I better off writing a Cloud Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly write a rule that checks that multiple documents are updated at the same time in order to preserve consistency.  From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents):

> For writes, you can use the getAfter() function to access the state of a document after a transaction or batch of writes completes but before the transaction or batch commits. Like get(), the getAfter() function takes a fully specified document path. You can use getAfter() to define sets of writes that must take place together as a transaction or batch.